# ES6 arrow (=>) functions incompatible with IE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm testing the following code in my AngularJs application, it works fine in Firefox, but IE11 throws a syntax error for the arrows:

```
myApp.run((EventTitle, moment) => {
  EventTitle.weekView = event => `${moment(event.startsAt).format('hh:mm')} event.title`;
});
```

What would be the syntax that would work for IE?

Comment: It's not supported in IE11. [This](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3D%3E) is a pretty good resource for what is and is not supported by various browsers

Comment: No, arrow functions aren't supported in IE. Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile ES6 code to ES5.

Comment: Wow nice, thanks for the link to the Babel tool, didn't even know such a tool existed. It work now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE11 doesn't support several ES6 features, including lambda functions and template literals.

A rough equivalent that should work is:

```
myApp.run(function(EventTitle, moment) {
  EventTitle.weekView = function(event) {
     return moment(event.startsAt).format('hh:mm') + " " + event.title;
  };
});
```

However, there are some ways in which arrow functions do not work in the same way as regular functions. You'll need to watch for the use of `this` keywords, for example.

Alternatively, if you use a transpiler like Babel (or a transpiled language like TypeScript), you can use newer language features like your original code, and automatically generate JavaScript code that will run in browsers that don't support those features.

Comment: You still have an arrow function!

Comment: @MattBurland: Good catch.

Comment: It's also still using [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which are also ES6 and not supported by IE.

Comment: .. string interpolation is neither not ES5

Comment: All right, how does it look now guys?

Comment: Thanks for your help, `});` should be `};`